# What's the best way to obtain an activity object for unit testing in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I need a generic activity object to test another class.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a mock ... inherit from Activity, and override whatever you need to override.

better yet, decouple the other class so that you don't have such a dependency on a framework class like Activity.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to get a handle to an Activity other than the activity under test in a unit test based on ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

However, as the other respondent said, it's not a great idea to make a class dependent on a fundamental Android component like Activity. What's the use case?